# Can I use a redirect_to in a Rails controller with JQTouch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqtouch

I have a UserSessions controller whose create action issues a "redirect_to dashboard_path" for the mobile mime type. The form is being submitted with a link_to, which JQTouch turns into an ajax request. JQTouch ends up sliding in a completely blank page with the #undefined anchor appended to the URL. I've determined that what it's doing is displaying the create.mobile.erb template for my UserSessions controller. The UserSessions controller should be redirecting to DashboardController#show though.

A pastie of my code is here: http://pastie.org/1161858

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here? I wish the JQTouch documentation wasn't so sparse.

Thanks in advance,
Sam